# Conflicting polygons in shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, select-by-location

In a QGIS-project I have a shapefile consisting of polygons. However some of the polygons are double and thus laying over each other. Is there a way I can select all these 'conflicting' polygons so I can delete them from the shape?